# Django Permissions -- same codename, different name issue

Tags: python, django, permissions, roles

If I happen to have separate models, each with corresponding permissions, but with the same codename, is there a way to distinguish between the two when checking to see if a User has the permissions of each individual type of model?

For example, I have two models, each with custom permissions like:

```
class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('can_execute', 'Can execute class1'),
        )

class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('can_execute', 'Can execute class2'),
        )
```

then, when checking if a user has these permissions, like

```
user.has_perm('app.can_execute')
```

is there no way to distinguish between the two? Should I always have it so that the codenames are distinct for each separate model?

Answer (score 1):

Django default permissions are per model and they have suffix of model name as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions)

> it will ensure that four default permissions – add, change, delete,
> and view – are created for each Django model defined in one of your
> installed applications.

---

> Assuming you have an application with an app_label foo and a model
> named Bar, to test for basic permissions you should use:
>
> ```
> add: user.has_perm('foo.add_bar')
> change: user.has_perm('foo.change_bar')
> delete: user.has_perm('foo.delete_bar')
> view: user.has_perm('foo.view_bar')
> ```

You could use same suffix schema to create your own custom permissions so that you don't have conflicts in naming

```
class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('can_execute_class2', 'Can execute'),
        )
```

Comment: so are you saying that, in the above example, I could check for permissions like "user.has_perm('app.can_execute_class1')" ?

Comment: I have edited my answer, if you use same permissions for all classes you can override default model permissions list and add that one too

Comment: ok so in other words, I will have to change the codenames so that they are distinct for each model?

Comment: yes, this is just an example of how django does it internally